# Is changing attributes on a bunch of img tags easier in jQuery than PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I was thinking of writing some code in PHP to change all the `id`s of images to match their `alt`s. Would this be easier to implement in jQuery?

What i need to do is take this line

img alt="puzzle" src="images/cole.jpg" alt="This is me" style="display:none;" />

and make it

img id="puzzle" alt="puzzle" src="images/cole.jpg" alt="This is me" style="display:none;" />

Comment: It really depends on how your system is setup. Cannot accurately answer this question without some clarification / code snippets. The gist though, give the one you prefer a shot and see how that goes, its not the end of the world if it fails and you have to revert to the other method. Just a learning experience.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Your input contains two ALT attributes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shift as much as possible to the server. Also what if the user has a javascript blocker on ?

But I would have to ask why would you want to do this?

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

But alt tags may have spaces, this means you could set a possibly invalid id!

**EDIT**

Now you have edited your answer:
That first `img` tag is invalid html, you cannot have 2 `alt` tags and jQuery will not be able to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one writing the scripts it's the same amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe jQuery will be a lot simpler since you can select ALL the images just once. I guess php would require more thinking and more code.

If the images are already there, jQuery will be easier.

If the images are created by php through a loop it'll be easier to do with the php.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is probably far better at parsing the DOM (read: less work for you), but it's going to be faster if you can do it at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

If this functionality is critical to the usability of your website, do it at the server level.  That way, if the client has Javascript disabled, they can still use the website as you intend it.

JQuery is great, and a vast majority of users have Javascript enabled, but I normally limit JQuery to non-critical add-ons to enhance the user experience.